# add item to next column in wrapgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I have a `GridView` like this

```
<GridView x:Name="TestGridView"  SelectionMode="None">                
  <GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="300" ItemHeight="80"  Height="480" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

One of my `GridViewItem` contains a button, when I click this `Button`, a new `GridViewItem` will added to the `GridView` dynamically, I want the maximum number of `GridViewItem` is 8, after the eighth `GridViewItem` added to the `GridView`, the `Button` collapsed. Then add some other `GridViewItem` in next column of the `GridView`, but the 8th `GridViewItem` doesn't occupy all the space of the 2nd column, if I add new `GridViewItem`, it will automatically added to the 2nd column below the 8th `GridViewItem`. How to explicitly add `GridViewItem` to the next column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use group, there is a group collection in gridview. you can just add 8 item in a group, and then set other in the new group.